# ImportError : No module named xxxx.msg

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone.
I migrate an installation from one computer to another, switching from Ubuntu 12.04 to 16.04 and from indigo ros to kinetic
When I run my installation that has about 30 packages most of the things seem to start well except for a package that fails to make an import
I specify that I do not have this error on the computer of the previous configuration, or everything is identical in my programs, except the denomination of indigo and kinetic
The error is as follows:

```
From my_folder_msgs.msg import my_file as My_fileMsg   
ImportError : No module named my_folder_msgs.msg
```

Of course, my_folder_msgs.msg  exists and appears when I call: rosmsg list.

Would anyone have an idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271620/importerror%C2%A0:-no-module-named-xxxx.msg/) by [pibauer](https://answers.ros.org/users/32037/pibauer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-09-27

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nico__](https://answers.ros.org/users/27606/nico__/) on 2017-09-27**:
Hi,
Make sure you got the "#!/usr/bin/env python" line at top of your python file, also make sure that youre customs messages are built. You can check with rosmsgs list | grep your_custom_msgs

Nicolas

**Comment by [pibauer](https://answers.ros.org/users/32037/pibauer/) on 2017-09-29**:
Thank you for your message.
everything was as you advised

**Comment by [mihir3445@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/53164/mihir3445@gmail.com/) on 2020-06-10**:
https://www.theconstructsim.com/solve-error-importerror-no-module-named-xxxx-msg-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @pibauer,

when we use our custom messages, even if they are listed with `rosmsg list`, they only can be used by our nodes after they be compiled.

I have created a video (https://youtu.be/NKeebwRNvv8) that answers exactly this question.

The steps explained in the video are basically the following:

1. You have to compile your message. For that, you have to touch the `package.xml` and `CMakeLists.txt` according to the instructions found on `CMakeLists.txt`. After prepare the `package.xml` and `CMakeLists.txt`, you run `catkin_make` on your `catkin_ws`
2. After the message is compiled, you have to source the `setup.bash` like: `source catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`
3. Now you can import your messages without any problem.

That is it. If you still have any questions, just ask here or watch the video aforementioned.

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2017-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pibauer](https://answers.ros.org/users/32037/pibauer/) on 2017-09-29**:
your video is super clear.
thank you for that clarification

**Comment by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) on 2017-09-29**:
You're Welcome.

Great to know that it helped.

If you can, just mark the answer as `correct`.

Cheers.

**Comment by [navibot](https://answers.ros.org/users/33737/navibot/) on 2018-03-18**:
Thanks this helped me too!  Just remember to load a new terminal or resource the setup script after compilation.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For those that don't like to watch videos and want an answer straightaway (this is taken right from the [wiki](https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv)):

Update your `package.xml` with:

```
<build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
<exec_depend>message_runtime</exec_depend>
```

This will tell the build system about the new message definitions.

Next, modify your `CMakeLists.txt` file by:

adding the following at the end of `find_package()`

```
find_package(
    ...
    # any packages your messages depend on such as std_msgs
    message_generation
)
```

export the message runtime dependency

```
catkin_package(
  ...
  CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime ...
  ...)
```

add any message files that you have defined and want to compile

```
add_message_files(
  FILES
  my_file.msg
)
```

call the `generate_messages()` function

```
generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs
  # and any other packages your messages depend on
)
```

Now, navigate to your workspace's root and compile using either

```
~/catkin_ws/$ catkin_make
```

or

```
~/catkin_ws/$ catkin build
```

and source your workspace

```
~/catkin_ws/$ source devel/setup.bash
```

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2019-04-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3